# Добавление в массив во время перебора PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Мне нужно во время перебора массива добавить новое значение в следующий элемент.
Делаю так:

```
foreach ($arr as $i => &$ar) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        array_splice($arr, $i+1, 0, '7');
    }
    echo "<br>".$i." - ".$ar;
}
```

Но на выводе:
0 - a
5 - f

Мне нужно именно добавить элемент, чтобы он следующий пошел на перебор ($+1)

Comment: Если делать $+2, то работает как надо, но мне нужно $+1

Comment: дайте пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: $arr = ['a','b','c','d','f']; и нужно чтобы перебор выполнился как ['a','7','b','c','d','f'];

Comment: вы сначала добавьте, а потом перебирайте. Каково условие ваше добавления то?

Comment: я бы тогда не писал сюда. мне нужно добавить элемент именно во время перебора.

Comment: Итератор защищен, в случае добавления во время итерации, даже если вы и добавите, через 2 среза, между одним срезом и вторым, добавите нужное значение, то итератор от этого не обновится, то есть значение, добавленное при `0 ==$i` не будет добавлено в итератор, хотя после завершения цикла, `var_dump($arr);` вернет с добавленным значением.

Comment: я это уже понял, поэтому и пишу сюда, на поиск решения

Comment: Просто не использовать `foreach` для этих целей. А например `while`, `for`, `Iterator` - классы. Где есть возможность добавлять во время работы цикла с обновлением счетчика

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать другой цикл:

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d','f'];

for ($i = 0, $j = count($arr); $i < $j; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        array_splice($arr, $i + 1, 0, '7');
        $j++;
    }
    echo "<br>$i - $arr[$i]";
}
```

---

```
0 - a
1 - 7
2 - b
3 - c
4 - d
5 - f
```